# Stack Overflow is not shown correctly

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design, firefox

Recently, I have experienced a rather strange problem with Stack Overflow.

I am using Mozilla FireFox as my browser.

It seems that the problem is with the stylesheet not functioning, so all the contents of the site is shown in plain text with a messed up style.I  have checked the page source and the related css file exists.

**Edited:**

More Info :

OS : Windows XP service pack 3

Browser : Mozilla Fire Fox 4.0.1

Comment: check cdn.sstatic.net not blocked?

Comment: More info please, Browser version, OS, AddOns, proxy or (corporate) firewall? If possible test with other browsers, too.

Comment: 1) Refresh the page. 2) Clear your cache. 3) Try another browser.

Comment: I have disabled all plugins and extensions , removed cookies ,checked access to cdn.sstatic.net (and it's not blocked) but the problem still remains. I am behind out company firewall but that can not be the issue because it was working fine two days before and nothing has changed since then.

Comment: `...and nothing has changed since then.` Can you guarantee that they haven't changed the rules?

Comment: No-repro here with FF4; this may be indeed an issue with your company's firewall and/or proxy.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with IE 8...Been going on since yesterday. Tried clearing the cache but no luck. I am also getting a `stackexchange is undefined` JS error on the page

Comment: This seems to be a recurring error: I had the same issue half a year ago, with FF 3.6 on Windows Vista; it vanished just by itself after a day or two.

Comment: xp looooooooooooooool

Comment: I had a similar problem this morning with SharePoint SE and I posted a question on SPSE Meta (http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149/stylesheet-not-working) but within 4 minutes everything was working again.

Answer (score 1):

I also saw this this morning on the train coming in to work.  I was browsing from my Adndroid phone with no addons, all standard Android config.

Comment: See this please http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93145/so-sites-do-not-load-all-the-css-files-in-the-android-browser