# Stack Exchange sites do not load all the CSS files in the Android browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It happened a couple of days ago. Clearing the cache did not help. This is what I see now:

[image]

This happens with other Stack Exchange sites also. Meta Stack Overflow, on the other hand, looks fine:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I configured the CDN incorrectly in one spot. I'm not entirely sure how or why this caused this issue – my theory at the moment is that the Android browser and the CDN outsmarted each other with regards to caching – but either way it should be fixed now.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as well, as @Sathya said, since a few days already.

Comment: @slhck: Fixed again (temporarily; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93563/the-cdn-configuration-strikes-back)